# Problema en el binding de datos con valor decimal formateado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

tengo una vista en la que muestro unos valores decimales con formato de la siguiente manera:

```
  @{
     for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
     {
           <tr>
           <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => @Model[i].Imp, "{0:n2}", new { @id = "Imp_" + i, @class = "form-control text-right mascara" })</td>
           <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => @Model[i].Ret, "{0:n2}", new { @id = "Ret_" + i, @class = "form-control text-right mascara" })</td>
        </tr>
     }
   }
```

El formato me aparece correctamente y por ejemplo el número 12000000 se visualiza como 12.000.000,00
El problema es que al hacer el post, este dato no se "bindea" correctamente y en el controlador recibo un 0. Sin embargo si el número es por ejemplo 123,45 sí que lo recibo correctamente, así que el problema viene en los números que tienen algún separador de miles.
He probado a decorar el view model así, pero tampoco funciona.

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
 public decimal Imp { get; set; }
```

Alguna idea de como solucionar esto?.

*Añado más info tal como me solicitan, el view model y la acción del controlador.*

```
 public class DatosImp_VM
 {
    public int EmpresaID { get; set; }
    public string NomEmpresa { get; set; }
    public decimal Imp { get; set; }
    public decimal Ret { get; set; }
 }       

 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Add(List<DatosImp_VM> param)
 {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       ;
    }

    return View(param);
 }
```

Comment: Puedes poner tu Post del controller?

Comment: Aun tienes problema con esto? Si es asi, entonces podrias poner como mandas tus datos de la vista al controller? Es un Ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he conseguido solucionarlo. Lo comento aquí por si a alguien más le puede ser de utilidad.

En primer lugar crear esta clase para sobreescribir el método:

```
 public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
 {
    ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
    ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
    object actualValue = null;

    try
    {
       actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
    catch (FormatException e)
    {
       modelState.Errors.Add(e);
    }
    bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
    return actualValue;
 }
```

Después incluir esto en Application_Start() del Glogal.asax:

```
 ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
```

Eso es todo. Obviamente se puede personalizar y adaptar a las necesidades de cada uno.